# SQL Server : syntax error when running INSERT INTO where exists and join

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to copy data from one table into another table if these rows are not already in the table. In addition I want to add the value from a column in a third table based on the value of the column in the original table being copied across.

I have inherited two tables one of which is to be made redundant (because the database is going to be made defunct) and hence the information needs to be moved to another table which is not identical in design (however the datatypes are).

```
INSERT INTO [AMData].[dbo].[AttendanceRecord] A ([TypeID], [Date], [EmpID], [EhrID], [SickReason], [AbsID])
   SELECT 
       T.[ID], F.[EHrDate], F.[EHrEmpID], F.[EHrID], F.[EHRUserComment], F.[AbsID]
   FROM 
       [Focus].[dbo].[AllAbsence] F 
   INNER JOIN 
       [AMData].[dbo].[AttendanceTypes] T ON F.[AbsID] = T.[FocusID]
   WHERE 
       NOT EXISTS (SELECT * 
                   FROM [AMData].[dbo].[AttendanceRecord] A, [Focus].[dbo].[AllAbsence] F
                   WHERE A.[EhrID] = F.[EHrID]
                     AND F.[EHrDate] BETWEEN '2018/01/01' AND '2018/12/01'
                     AND F.[AbsID] <> 0 
                     AND F.[AbsID] <> 2);
```

I am getting a syntax error when I try to run the code. I am not used to running insert code so there is probably obviously wrong.

Comment: *"I am getting a syntax error"* You forgot to tell us the error. :)

Comment: use `MERGE` to merge two tables in sql-server

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**25 years** ago) and its use is discouraged. And for **string literals** representing dates, I'd **strongly recommend** using the modified ISO-8601 format: **YYYYMMDD** - no dashes, no slashes - nothing. That's the only format that works always

Answer (score 1):

A guess, but I suspect the problem is you are aliasing the table `AttendanceRecord`. You can't alias a table in the `INSERT` clause. The error is actually telling you this:

> Ln: 1 Col: 47 - Incorrect syntax near 'A'

Remove the `A` and this will work (well, the below SQL doesn't have a syntax error, so I use the word "work" loosely):

```
INSERT INTO [AMData].[dbo].[AttendanceRecord] ([TypeID],
                                               [Date],
                                               [EmpID],
                                               [EhrID],
                                               [SickReason],
                                               [AbsID])
SELECT T.[ID],
       F.[EHrDate],
       F.[EHrEmpID],
       F.[EHrID],
       F.[EHRUserComment],
       F.[AbsID]
FROM [Focus].[dbo].[AllAbsence] AS F
     INNER JOIN [AMData].[dbo].[AttendanceTypes] AS T ON F.[AbsID] = T.[FocusID]
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                  FROM [AMData].[dbo].[AttendanceRecord] AS A,
                       [Focus].[dbo].[AllAbsence] AS F
                  WHERE A.[EhrID] = F.[EHrID]
                    AND F.[EHrDate] BETWEEN '2018/01/01' AND '2018/12/01'
                    AND F.[AbsID] <> 0
                    AND F.[AbsID] <> 2);
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the help. That runs. I was banging my head wondering what it could be. Kind Regards